# Storing triples in Node.js

Tags: node.js, triplestore

I'm developing an app in [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and I have my data in json representation of a triple, as so:

```
{
    subject:"Hello",
    predicate:"Knows",
    object:"World"
}
```

I'd like to be able to store my data into a [data|triple]store in  relatively straightforward manner.

The data values within the tuple also need to searchable.

I was looking at using existing RDF server and accessing it via HTTP, but would like to avoid using Sparql (a workaround might be to have a separate javascript module which wraps around the Sparql).

Are there any existing Node modules which deal with storing triples?  If not, what would be a pragmatic solution to storing triples?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to access the data by a key (such as a user id), use a Key-Value store like [Redis](http://redis.io), and connect to it with [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).

If you need to do searches on the data within the triple, then use [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org) and connect to it with something like [Mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose).

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, I'm not aware of any data store that is optimized to store 3-tuples (triples) for Node.js. Without knowing more about the problem that you're solving and the relevant domain, it's tough to provide specific advice. With the current information that you've provided, for each triple, I'd create a key. Then choose either [MongoDB](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native) (probably an overkill), [Redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) (Hash or Set) or a JavaScript associative array depending upon your requirements.

If you're looking for performance amongst many Node.js clients, then using Redis with the would work excellent.

Answer (score 2):

To start, your example is not a valid RDF triple, so if you really want to go w/ RDF, you're going to have to be stricter with your data.

With that said, there's a couple options that I know of out there, [this](https://github.com/webr3/rdf-interfaces) framework implements the proposed RDF *interface* standard in Javascript.  Don't know if you can hook it up to an existing triple store or what, but it might work for representing your data.  [This library](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/) works with jQuery for providing some RDF support.  Lastly there's [this library](https://github.com/dnewcome/jstle) which tried to be a compact RDF representation in Javascript.

Another option is the [RDF/JSON LD spec](http://json-ld.org/spec/latest/) which with its JSON representation is fairly amenable to use in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I just made a very lightweight JS framework to does exactly what you want :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexastore

Add triples :

```
mydb.putAll([
  ["hexastore","is","nice"],
  ["hexastore","speed","fast"],
  ["javascript","is","nice"]
]);
```

Query triples :

```
var result = db.search([
  [["what"],"is","nice"]
]);
// result == [{what:hexastore},{what:javascript}]
```